# No brightness controls after fresh install

Tags: release-juno

I'm a long time Mac user, Elementary is very elegant and the minimal aspect great

Still some functions are essential... I'm missing the *brightness controls*. I tried every keyboard shortcut and looked Elementary's "system preferences" several times but couldn't find any command to adjust brightness

Installing 3rd party tools to adjust brightness didn't work either because they were outdated and the only software `Dimmer` available on the "app store" didn't go along with Night light: if night light switches on, dimmer switches off and vice versa. Furthermore, `Dimmer` doesn't dim very much even on Max, therefore I'm basically without brightness control.

I played with the idea to install another kernel but...in a virtual machine. Anyway I don't like such experiments as Elementary shouldn't need such "unofficial hacks" self contained as it *should* be

Answer (score 1):

Please click on the battery icon from [wingpanel](/questions/tagged/wingpanel)(top bar) you will be able to increase or decrease the screen brightness from there.

Also if you go to [system](/questions/tagged/system) [settings](/questions/tagged/settings) and then [power](/questions/tagged/power), you can see another bar to increase or decrease the screen brightness.

Hope this helps. Please do let me know what you find.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood and ``brightness = night light``? I installed Juno on my desktop. There's no battery nor such a menu

Comment: Please look at both picture, one is [nightlight](https://ibb.co/mbwzd6w) and the other is [brightness](https://ibb.co/YTw3ZHC). Hope your confusion is clear.

Comment: Thanks for you support Hasan. I have ``night light``.  I haven't ever seen ``brightness``. This menu doesn't exist on my setup. I downloaded Juno from your main website. It's known that Ubuntu and derivatives have problems with brightness settings as much I have read online. Maybe you know a terminal command to repair this issue?  Thanks

Comment: Let's talk in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93057/discussion-on-answer-by-hasan-no-brightness-controls-after-fresh-install).